# When the sales_flat_order_item.qty_cancelled gets value?

Tags: magento-enterprise, sales-order, edit-order

When the sales_flat_order_item.qty_cancelled gets value? Is it updated as a result of RMA process? I am sure it is not updated when a credit memo is raised.

Answer (score 1):

"`sales_flat_order_item.qty_cancelled`" Will be updated once the Order or Order item gets cancelled.

Comment: We are cancelling an entire order. We can't cancel a single item, right?

Comment: Magento default having cancellation of full order, We can customize based on item also

Comment: Does this qty_cancelled get updated when we cancell individual items? I tried canelling the whole order OOTB, but it doesn't update this field.